# Gradle after update cannot see a property

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After updating a gradle to newest version I receive a crash:

```
**ERROR: Cannot get property 'fileExtension' on extra properties extension as it does not exist**
```

Android library module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply from: "../artifactory/release.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion project.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion project.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion project.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode project.versionCode
        versionName project.versionName

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}


project.ext {
    name = "library-module"
    fileExtension = "aar" //file extension is defined in this module (not root project like other dependencies
}
```

release.gradle (file that does not see external properties):

```
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply from: "../artifactory/config.gradle"




publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId project.groupId
            version project.versionName
            artifactId project.name
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-release.${project.ext.fileExtension}")
        }}}
```

strange fact: project name is defined in library module (but is seen in release.gradle file)

Comment: I guess the variable `fileExtension` is not defined in the `gradle.properties` or somewhere else? If you have a previous version, Then compare them.

Comment: You should have to use `rootProject` instead of `project`. So final statement be like `${rootProject.ext.fileExtension}`

Comment: but what if fileExtension depends on sub-modules (libraries), where should it be defined?